# A basic question with yum

Tags: linux, yum, dependencies, libraries

I am trying to edit the source of a package and make it work. Thus, I didnt use yum install, I installed it from source and it is working. The package im building from source is libvirt. Now I want to install libvirt-python. I used yum install libvirt-python. It says, libvirt is not installed, Dependency libvirt.so.0 missing and it has to install it. But I want this libvirt-python to be installed on top of the libvirt i compiled. I know that libvirt.so.0 is in /lib . Can someone tell me how i can tell yum the current location of the libvirt.so.0 (By using a symbolic link or something) and install libvirt-python without using libvirt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- recompile the libvirt with `--prefix=/usr/local/libvirt`
- `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/libvirt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try the following:

```
yum install --tolerant --exclude=libvirt libvirt-python
```

Regards

Stephan